# How to Set Progress Bar?

Tags: android

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public ListView lisView1;
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;
    public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetNotificationList";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // listView1
        lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        ShowData();
    }

    public void ShowData() {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML



          Document  doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        int displayPerPage = 5; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();
        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }
        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

            RowID = RowID + 1;

        }

        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName });
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
    }

}
```

This is My Source code and I want to set ProgressBar this activity is calling from another activity on Button click I want set ProgressBar when data is loading ShowData() function we have use for Parsing Printing,and pagination I tried Much but I am not able to put ProgressBar For loading data please tell me how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it will work..

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public ListView lisView1;
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;
    public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetNotificationList";
    SimpleAdapter sAdap;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Activity mActivity;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mActivity = this;
        // listView1
        lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                new backProcess().execute();
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;
                new backProcess().execute();
            }
        });

        new backProcess().execute();
    }

    public void ShowData() {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        int displayPerPage = 5; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();
        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }
        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

            RowID = RowID + 1;

        }

    }

    public class backProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this,
                    menuItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "RowID",
                            KEY_NAME },
                    new int[] { R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName });
            lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Wait",
                    "Loading...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ShowData();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few good tutorials available (ex http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html)

Comment: i Have tired Much am not able to do it then i have Post i have seen that But there is Problem coming when i use that logic please tell me code Using asynk task

Answer (score -1):

use the Async Task to load the data

```
private class Data extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

             ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "",
                    "Loading...");

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            //do hard work here
                            ShowData();
                                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            progress.getProgress();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

            progressBar.dismiss();


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

and on the onclick method

```
new Data().execute().
```

Comment: onclick   method is in my another class how i will call this ?

Comment: this subclass class must only in that class call which you want to call and in onclick method class call like this "new Data().execute();"

Comment: Not able to do please tell me ur email id i ll send u Source code so that u can see and Implement it i tried last 2 days not able to do

Comment: i will try naveenkumar947@yahoo.com

Comment: I m Sending u mail Just now please help me i m trying to implemnt last 2 days

Comment: Naveen Please check ur mail i have sent mail  naveenkumar947@yahoo.com in his id

Answer (score -1):

Make async class as public static and then you can access it from anywhere.

```
private class Data extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

         ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "",
                "Loading...");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //do hard work here
                        ShowData();
                            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progress.getProgress();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        progressBar.dismiss();


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: same thing i did it show progress bar then application becomes close

Comment: when i use next ,previous and one more place new data().execute();

Comment: can u please tell me ur email id show that i can send u Source code and u can check it

Comment: @DeepikaLalra dont copy answer of others

Comment: @CapDroid i was just make him know your answer is correct but way to implement is incorrect. aplogies if you feel bad. :( but i am just trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @DeepikaLalra doing help is good.I proud of u but you did copy & U didn't changed anything in code. If code it working then no issue but in this code many mistake so I aware to u